# Openlayers 3 set icon pointerEvents to none for click through

Tags: openlayers

I've read through the OL3 API documentation without finding how or where to disable click on an icon so the map underneath gets the click instead.

Perhaps it's not possible?
Or does it go in ol.Feature, ol.style.Style or ol.style.Icon somehow?

code example...

```
xFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0,0])
    });
xStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
        anchor: [40,40],
        anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: 'image.png'
        }))
    });
xFeature.setStyle(xStyle);
```

**Update 1:** erilem has helped me understand that clicks are ignored by default. Further in my code I am using forEachFeatureAtPixel which is obviously intercepting the click.

```
map.on('click', function(evt){
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature, layer){
            return feature;
            });
    if(feature){
        /* do whatever */
        }
    });
```

**My Solution** add uuid to icon feature & ignore that in click iteration

```
xFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0,0]),
    uuid: 1
    });
xStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
        anchor: [40,40],
        anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: 'image.png'
        }))
    });
xFeature.setStyle(xStyle);

map.on('click', function(evt){
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature, layer){
            if( feature.get('uuid') != 1 ){
                    return feature;
                    }
            });
    if(feature){
        /* do whatever */
        }
    });
```

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What do you mean by "disable click on an icon so the map underneath gets the click instead"?

Comment: For an icon on the map that needs to ignore click/tap events. For example a double tap to zoom the map needs to be ignored by this icon and pass through to the map.

Comment: Clicks on icons are ignored by default. Do you use a Select interaction? Or do you use `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` in a "click" listener?

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I updated my question with what I figured out. Feel welcome to rephrase your comment into an answer or answer it more to spec. I don't feel right answering my question since you pin pointed my issue. On the same token this should be helpful to future OL3 users googling around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `forEachFeatureAtPixel` and want to exclude a specific feature (`xFeature` in your example) from the "feature detection" then you can just use a simple test in the `forEachFeatureAtPixel` callback:

```js
var xFeature = new ol.Feature(...);

map.on('click', function(evt){
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    if(feature !== xFeature) {
      return feature;
    }
  });
  if (feature) {
    /* do whatever */
  }
});
```